# Returning an NSString from an NSError

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nserror

I am using the `NSURLRequest` class in my iPhone app, and the method that calls it returns an `NSString` which is great for when the connection goes through ok, but the issue is I need to convert the NSError into an NSString so I can either return it back or run some `if()` statements on it.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: Could you give a code sample of the problem.

Comment: PARSE CLOUD CODE,  `response.error("duplicate-email-in-employee");` then in iOS, `[employee saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
    {
    if (error)
        {
        if ([error.localizedDescription
                    isEqualToString:@"duplicate-email-in-employee"]) { ...`

Answer (score 85, accepted):

[`-[NSError localizedDescription]`](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001704-BBCDFIAF).

(Also, every ObjC object inherited from NSObject implements `-description` which returns an NSString.)

Answer (score 14):

for folks new to objective c (me), following is example code that makes accepted answer from 'KennyTM' work ->

```
[self showAlertWithTitle:@"Error:" withMessage:error.localizedDescription];
```

Answer (score 7):

You could try the `localizedDescription` method, which returns a string.

More in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nserror?language=objc).

Answer (score 5):

I found that there are three main methods to [`NSError`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

- error (NSInteger)
- domain (NSString)
- userInfo (NSDictionary)

Answer (score 3):

To get all the error details:

```
NSError * err;
...
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", err];
```